Is there a way to hide some objects in Model Browser Tree but keep them on scene?
I need to hide an object completely in Model Browser but keep it visible on a scene.
I've tried some approaches, including this one:
Hiding object on the model tree panel
But it didn't work for me as viewer.modelstructure.createUI() function does not exists.
Additionally the tree object in viewer.modelstructure is null. I can't access elements directly.
Also setModelStructurePanel function is marked deprecated now so I can't use that either. (Edit: I made a mistake here; the function is not deprecated but for some reason it does not exists for the viewer object)
(Edit) I've also tried using approach with getting element by lmv-nodeid but that does not work for me either as these elements are not created until the user opens Model Browser. But more than that, I have the actual model elements in a sub-category, so when I open Model Browser, I see only collapsed sub-categories which may contain other sub-categories, etc. And the needed element with lmv-nodeid does not exist until I open all the sub-categories. This way I cannot use the approach with lmv-nodeid.
I'm using @contecht/react-adsk-forge-viewer React Typescript wrapper for the Forge Viewer, maybe this is the cause.

lmv-nodeid is node dbId, you can get it from inspect element or traversing through object tree, easier way is inspect element.
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_ACTIVATED_EVENT,async(e)=>{
    if(e.extensionId == "Autodesk.ModelStructure" && e.type=="extensionActivated"){
       let lmvnodeid = 939;  // change this in your case. For multiple nodes, change this to array and put the below code in for loop
       let node = document.querySelectorAll('[lmv-nodeid="' + lmvnodeid + '"]')[0]
       node.style.display = 'none'
    }
});


EDIT: I got it working with dynamic CSS selectors. On extension activated or even before run this code to add style to webpage.
// 7884 is the lmv nodeid.
const addCSS = css => document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).innerHTML=css;
addCSS('div[lmv-nodeid*="7884"]{display:none!important}')


Thank you, but this one doesn't work for me either, I have edited my answer. Forgot to mention that while writing the question. Because of sub-categories these elements with the needed id's do not exist if I just open model browser.

if it helps, onElementIconClick from TreeOnDemand is the function for expanding sub-categories. inside ModelStructureTreeDelegate.prototype.onTreeNodeIconClick collapse is being set to true. unfortunately, there are no events or callback options on expanding subcategories

@Artem I have added the solution for your case of sub categories. Please check.
